# How to check permission in jsp if tag

Tags: jsp, struts2, spring-security, jsp-tags

I want to check if user has some role permission and I want to check it using if else statement. I wrote this and it is not working,

```
<s:if test="%{hasRole('SOME_ROLE') == 1}">
    <input type="hidden" id='isHasRole' value = 'true'>
</s:if>
<s:else>
    <input type="hidden" id='isHasRole' value = 'false'>
</s:else>
```

It always gives false. Can anyone help me on this.
Thanks.

Comment: Try to call the same method in java class and make sure it's working properly.

Comment: it is working properly with access tag. Is this way correct ?

Comment: Do you mean spring-security `hasRole`? Use spring-security tags.

Comment: @AleksandrM Yes I mean Spring-secirity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
<sec:authorize
    access="hasRole('SOME_ROLE')">
        <input type="hidden" id='isHasRole' value = 'true'>
</sec:authorize>
```

when there is no permission for user it returns "undefine".